# Disable driver/module loaded by the Kernel while booting

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

When my embedded Linux OS boots up the driver st_drv and btwilink are getting loaded ,But I need to load the modules in a specific order ,which is as follows..

1. First load st_drv module (modprobe st_drv)
2. Run a application called uim in /usr/sbin
3. Load the btwilink module (modprobe btwilink)

I've looked /etc/modules or /etc/modules.conf file but no name of the above modules is present there

**How can I disable these two driver/module loaded by the Kernel while booting itself?**

**NB: I use linux 3.12 kernel which uses Device tree**

Answer (score 1):

For this,

1. You can move the modules from  the default path and then create a new module dependency,

   > go to **/lib/modules/your_kernel_version/kernel** 
   >   Generally **your_kernel_versoin** would something similar **3.4.23-generic**
2. Locate the modules **st_drv and btwilink** from that directory, then move those to some other folder.
3. Create a new dependency list with the other modules using the **depmod** command 
   $ depmod .
4. Now you can reboot your PC and be sure that the drivers st_drv and btwilink are not loaded, verify using **lsmod**
5. Note: make sure you have root user permission